# how to compute the result in an android calculator

Tags: android, textview, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator where the user enters the data in one line, and then upon pressing "=" it computes the result. However, I do not know how to take in the data entered for the computation.
1) do I take in the whole string and compute it (which means android will have to be able to distinguish signs such as + and - ) 
2) or do I take in the data one by one as the user enters the numbers.
So far I have this:

```
public void onClickButton (View view)
    {
        if (view.getId() == (R.id.Button01)){
            txtView1.append("7");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button02)){
            txtView1.append("8");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button03)){
            txtView1.append("9");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button04)){
            txtView1.append("/");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button05)){
            txtView1.append("4");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button06)){
            txtView1.append("5");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button07)){
            txtView1.append("6");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button08)){
            txtView1.append("+");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button09)){
            txtView1.append("1");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button10)){
            txtView1.append("2");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button11)){
            txtView1.append("3");
        } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.Button12)){
            txtView1.append("-");
        }
    }
```

This gets the text to come out in one string
eg: "5+45"

Comment: you should make a variable to store the first number if they press +,-,*,or /, and four booleans for each press of +,-,*,or / and make the appropriate one true, then when they press '=' do the appropriate calculation with all of the information youve collected

Comment: This would only work for 2 numbers though right?

Comment: every time you select an operator store the result in the variable, thats all, then you can do as many numbers as you want

Comment: @JRowan What will be answer for 5+4*6-7/8 according to your approach?

Comment: 9,then 54, then 47, then 5.875

Comment: its not in the order of operations, idk, im not making the program, im just trying to offer advice

Comment: @JRowan answer will be 28.125, expressions are evaluated as per [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#The_standard_order_of_operations)

Comment: Wow... alright.. how can I evaluate for the order of operations?

Comment: @user2883071 ..i already mentioned that in my answer. The standard way is to convert the infix expression to postfix(or prefix) expression and then evaluate the postfix(or prefix)expression .

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the expression in your textview from INFIX TO POSTFIX.
And after that you need to do evaluation of the obtained POSTFIX expression

[THIS TUTORIAL WILL BE HELPFUL TO UNDERSTAND THE ALGORITHM](http://geekswithblogs.net/venknar/archive/2010/07/09/algorithm-for-infix-to-postfix.aspx)